# step 2 of CFG conversion to Chomsky's normal form

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

in the step where you have to remove the epsilons, would you need to remove something like this:

A -> Bε

Or would you simply remove the ones that have epsilon by itself like this:

A -> ε

Comment: Hint: $B\varepsilon = B$.